# Is Airpod Pro knock-off using H1 Chip?

Tags: hardware, airpods, firmware

I got my hands on Chinese Airpod pro knock-off that came with Apple logo and surprisingly same packaging with additional buds.

Also to my surprise they were paired with iphone quite quickly just like a real airpod would by opening the case and pressing the button at the back. Now this makes me believe that they could have exact same H1 chip that comes with real Airpod pro.

**Question**: Does iphone detects the type of airpod by detecting the firmware on the H1 chip? Can H1 chip be duplicated along with the firmware such that it could fool iphone into detecting fake as real?

Comment: something tells me the fact that they are openly available in amazon with the logo of apple, it could be same company that is manufacturing them using same chip but perhaps with few inferior components. I have a friend who bought them and mentioned that noise-cancellation is not available and battery level always show 97% , he however did mention that the sound quality was quite good though, so it could be that it might not by H1 chip at all.  Now this is just educated speculation.

Comment: @metron, yes I can confirm both that noise-cancellation doesnt work but its still an option in GUI. The sound is great!